# How can I left align my signature in a resume written in the res class?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, resume

I want to add a signature at the end of my resume which I wrote in in the `res` class (with the `margin` option). How can I achieve this?

Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[margin, 10pt]{res} 
\usepackage{helvet} 
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.1in} 

\begin{document}
\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{\large\bf John Smith} % Your name at the top

\moveleft\hoffset\vbox{\hrule width\resumewidth height 1pt}\smallskip 

\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{123 Broadway} 
\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{City, State 12345}
\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{(000) 111-1111 or (111) 111-1112}

\begin{resume}

\section{EDUCATION}

{\sl Bachelor of Science,} Interdisciplinary Science \\
Rensselaer Polytechnic Institute, Troy, NY, expected December 1990 \\
Concentration: Computer Science \\
Minor: Management

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

My problem is that, when I try to embed my signature after `\end{resume}`, then it isn't fully on the left side.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Answer (score 3):

The `margin` option to this class has the effect of moving the left margin in an amount correspanding to `\sectionwidth`.  You need a way to provide either text in the left margin, like the section headings, or text sperading accross the full page.  Here is some code to achieve this:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[margin, 10pt]{res} 
\usepackage{helvet} 
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.1in} 


\newcommand{\lmargintext}[1]{\hbox to 0pt{\hss \vtop{\hsize=\sectionwidth #1}}}

\newlength{\bodywidth}
\setlength{\bodywidth}{\textwidth}

\newenvironment{fullwidthtext}{\hbox to \textwidth\bgroup\hss
\vtop\bgroup\hsize=\sectionwidth\advance\hsize by \bodywidth}{\egroup\egroup}

\begin{document}
\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{\large\bf John Smith} % Your name at the top

\moveleft\hoffset\vbox{\hrule width\resumewidth height 1pt}\smallskip 

\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{123 Broadway} 
\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{City, State 12345}
\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{(000) 111-1111 or (111) 111-1112}

\begin{resume}

\section{EDUCATION}

\textsl{Bachelor of Science,} Interdisciplinary Science \\
Rensselaer Polytechnic Institute, Troy, NY, expected December 1990 \\
Concentration: Computer Science \\
Minor: Management

\lmargintext{My Name}

\medbreak

\begin{fullwidthtext}
Writing text accross the whole page is done as
follows.  There may be several sentences containing plenty of text.  

And new paragraphs with long text.
\end{fullwidthtext}
\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

The above commands mimic the way the class builds the section headings.  The source code of the class notes that such commands remain to be defined.

The `fullwidthtext` environemnt defined above packs its argument in to one box and so will not break across pages.  This is probably exactly what you need for a signature.  However, an alternative list based definition that does allow page breaks is:

```
\newenvironment{fullwidthtext}{\list{}{\leftmargin-\sectionwidth\itemindent0pt}\item[]}{\endlist}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to move to the left by `\hoffset`

```
\documentclass[margin, 10pt]{res}
\usepackage{helvet}
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.1in}

\begin{document}
\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{\large\bf John Smith} % Your name at the top

\moveleft\hoffset\vbox{\hrule width\resumewidth height 1pt}\smallskip

\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{123 Broadway}
\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{City, State 12345}
\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{(000) 111-1111 or (111) 111-1112}

\begin{resume}

\section{EDUCATION}

{\sl Bachelor of Science,} Interdisciplinary Science \\
Rensselaer Polytechnic Institute, Troy, NY, expected December 1990 \\
Concentration: Computer Science \\
Minor: Management

\end{resume}
\hspace{-\hoffset}Signature
\end{document}
```